# Calling business logic layer from code behind

Tags: javascript, c#, asp.net, ajax

I have a page that I want to pass values to a service (already set up) and retrieve the **jobid** back. Being new to asp.net/javascript/ajax etc and going off previous newbie questions i've asked, I'm just wanting to check if the way I'm going about this is correct. The below code works, but is it the best way of doing things? (this is just a test page to show the logic)

Many thanks in advance for any advice

**test.aspx**

```
<head runat="server">
    <title></title>
    <script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/1.11.2/jquery.min.js"></script>
    <script type="text/javascript">

        function submitJob() {
            var propID = $get("textBox1").value;
            var dateReceived = $get("textBox2").value;
            var csJobTypeID = $get("textBox3").value;
            var notes = $get("textBox4").value;

            PageMethods.SubmitForm(propID, dateReceived, csJobTypeID, notes, fnsuccesscallback, fnerrorcallback);

        }

        function fnsuccesscallback(data) {
            $get("textBox5").value = data;

        }
        function fnerrorcallback(result) {
            alert(result.statusText);
        }

    </script>
</head>
<body>
    <form id="form1" runat="server">
    <asp:ScriptManager ID="ScriptManager" runat="server" EnablePageMethods="true" />
    <div>
        <asp:TextBox id="textBox1" runat="server">D2BAC8B9-DB94-E411-AE6D-00505696BEC2</asp:TextBox>
        <asp:TextBox id="textBox2" runat="server">2015-04-20T12:00:00</asp:TextBox>
        <asp:TextBox id="textBox3" runat="server">{4F1B4C1C-7179-E411-A36F-005056966B32}</asp:TextBox>
        <asp:TextBox id="textBox4" runat="server">These are the notes</asp:TextBox>
        <br />
        <br />
        <asp:TextBox ID="textBox5" runat="server" name="textBox5" ></asp:TextBox>
        <br />
        <br />
        <button id="btnTest" type="button" onclick="submitJob();">Test</button>
    </div>
    </form>
</body>
```

**test.aspx.cs**

```
    public partial class test : System.Web.UI.Page
    {

        [WebMethod]
        public static string SubmitForm(Guid propID, DateTime dateReceived, string csJobType, string notes)
        {

            Guid newJobID = NewJobBLL.NewJobID(propID, dateReceived, csJobType, notes);

            return newJobID.ToString();
        }

    }
}
```

**NewJobBLL.cs**

```
   public class NewJobBLL
    {

        public static Guid NewJobID(Guid propID, DateTime dateReceived, string csJobTypeID, string notes)
        {

            Job job = new Job() {
            LocationId = propID,
            DateReceived = dateReceived,
            ContractSpecificJobtypeID = csJobTypeID,
            Description = notes
        };

            CrmServiceHelper.SetUp(Utility.Enums.System.SystemEnvironment.Staging);

            ServiceResponseData<Job> response = CrmServiceHelper.JobService.InsertJob(job);


            if (response.CallSuccess)
            { 
                JobID = response.Data.JobCrmID;
            }

            return JobID;

        }

        public static Guid JobID
        {
            get;
            set;
        }


    }
```

Comment: This jobid is some kind of secret or not ?

Comment: I would say it's okay for a first time school project, but if you want to do it in a better way, I would suggest looking into the Repository Pattern and Decependency Injection

Comment: @MairajAhmad ? I don't understand what you mean sorry

Comment: @JunePaik thanks June, I will look into those

Comment: I mean any data sent back by webmethod using ajax can be seen in browser so if it confidential you must change this approach if it is not than you can use this,

Comment: @MairajAhmad ah ok - no, it's not confidential - it's on an internal network anyway - but if it was, what would I need to look at? Not using ajax?

Comment: Yes if it was than you should not use ajax.